# Yii2 $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) does not load data from form

Tags: php, database, forms, yii

When I take out condition to load data it saves it to db, the $_POST gets values but doesnt send them to controller , this way works in my other projects but not here. If I use `if(isset($_POST['money']) && isset($_POST['username'])){` to save data it works but not the `load()` function.

Controller

```
public function actionSend() {
    $model = new User();
    $model->getErrors();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->money = 'something';
        $model->username = 'something';
        $model->save();
    }
    return $this->render('send', [
        'model' => $model
    ]);
}
```

Model

```
<?php

namespace app\models;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

use Yii;

class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord {
    public static function tableName() {
        return 'user';
    }

    public function rules() {
        return [
            [['username', 'money'], 'safe'],
            [['username', 'password'], 'string', 'max' => 15],
            [['auth_key', 'access_token'], 'string', 'max' => 32],
            [['money'], 'string', 'max' => 8],
        ];
    }

    public function attributeLabels() {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'username' => 'Username',
            'password' => 'Password',
            'auth_key' => 'Auth Key',
            'access_token' => 'Access Token',
            'money' => 'Money',
        ];
    }
}
```

view

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
?>

<h2>Send</h2>

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'layout' => 'horizontal',
    'fieldConfig' => [
        'template' => "{label}\n<div class=\"col-lg-3\">{input}</div>\n<div class=\"col-lg-8\">{error}</div>",
        'labelOptions' => ['class' => 'col-lg-1 control-label'],
    ],
]); ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(['name' => 'username']) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'money')->textInput(['name' => 'money'])?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-11">
            <?= Html::submitButton('Send', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: `$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post(), '')` the empty second parameter must be empty if you don't have fields name in the form as ModelName[fieldName] or forms not created using form helpers of framework

Answer (score 15):

Change your controller to this

```
public function actionSend() {
    $model = new User();
    $model->getErrors();

    /* set the second parameters of load to empty string */
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post(), '')) {
        $model->money = 'something';
        $model->username = 'something';
        $model->save();
    }
    return $this->render('send', [
        'model' => $model
    ]);
}
```

If you review the implementation of [load](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/base/Model.php#L827) method, you would find that
`load` takes two parameters, the first is the data you want to assign, the second is the data's prefix name.

Let's look at an example to illustrate the usage of the second parameter. (We assume that your formname is `User`)

```
$data1 = [
    'username' => 'sam',
    'money' => 100
];

$data2 = [
    'User' => [
        'username' => 'sam',
        'money' => 100
    ],
],

// if you want to load $data1, you have to do like this
$model->load($data1, '');

// if you want to load $data2, you have to do like this
$model->load($data2);

// either one of the two ways, the result is the same.
echo $model->username;    // sam
echo $model->money;       // 100
```

Hope it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Let's Look The Below Example: 
Validate Objects or Array key with value with mode

```
//CONVERT OBJECT TO ARRAY
        $model_data = \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::toArray($json);

Array
(
    [device_id] => abcd
    [device_type] => android
    [c_id] => 38   
    [device_for] => rent   
    [area_id] => 1
    [city_id] => 1
)
```

Let's Load Array Data to Model

```
//LOAD POST DATA IN MODEL
$model->setAttributes($model_data);



if ($model->validate()) {

}else{

}
```